# element.style and element.setAttribute(attribute, value) is not the same?

Tags: html, css, typescript

I read multiple posts where people claim there is no difference. However, when I type following lines into console, only the first works

```
document.body.style.color = "red";

document.body.setAttribute("color", "red");
```

I tried it with different elements, not just with body. What is the difference?

thank you

Comment: I think you mean `document.body.setAttribute("style", "color: red");` You'd set the style attribute, not the color attribute.

Comment: because that would be `<body color="red">`

Comment: setAttribute means set an attribute on the HTML element being referenced. In this case, you're applying it to the body element. <body style="color: red;">

In your first example, you're referencing the attribute directly (style) by using document.body.style. In the second example you are explicitly stating which attribute you're setting and what you're setting the value to, as per Ray Hatfield's comment. There is no such thing as an HTML color attribute.

Comment: Thank you I don't know how I could overlook such an obvious thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAttribute` sets a value for an HTML attribute. For example:

```js
p1.setAttribute('foo', 'bar') // <p foo="bar">
p2.setAttribute('baz', '') // <p baz>
p3.setAttribute('style', 'color: red') // <p style="color: red">
```

Modifying the properties of `style` allows you to change the inline style for an element (the `style` attribute). This is kind of a shorthand for `setAttribute('style', style)` but is easier to use because you can change individual CSS properties without affecting the others. For example:

```js
document.body.style.color = 'red' // <body style="color: red">
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue' // <body style="color: red; background-color: blue">
```

The reason why `document.body.setAttribute('color', 'red')` does not work is because it is setting the `color` attribute to `red` without actually changing the style, resulting in

```html
<body color="red">
```